# how sequence maintain concurrency in oracle

Tags: oracle, concurrency, sequence

what happened, if sequence has been access at the same time (**even in milliseconds**) by multiple users. Whether it will be dead lock or Oracle have some mechanism ?

I mean, If A and B users has requested for `nextval` from `squence1` at same time, then they will get same value or they will hanged.

According to [this blog](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2008/12/oracle-sequences-and-concurrency.html), it says

> Concurrent access of NextVal on a sequence will always return separate
>   values to each caller. (Unless the sequence has been setup to cycle
>   values - in which case duplicate values are possible).

Comment: They are **guaranteed** to generate different values. Internally they are protected with a memory synchronization mechanism (which is much lighter than locking on database level)

Comment: can you please elaborate with some example..i'll really appreciate

Comment: Sorry I don't have the Oracle source code, so I cannot give an example. You will simply need to trust the manual here (and the fact that this has been working for over 30 years now). You might want to read Tom Kyte's book "Expert Oracle Database Architecture" which explains the different synchronizsation strategies in detail.

Comment: actually, it was an interview question and i was looking for answer, by which i can proof that, whatever i'm saying, is correct. Even, i'm totally agree with you, but if you have any trusted links where it is well explained, then please share.

Comment: A trusted link? Well the manual should be a "trusted link": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6015.htm

Comment: ahhhhh!!!! now what to say... it was very clear question, and people say **It's difficult to tell what is being asked here**... lolzz for them. **If you people can't understand this question, then I don't know how to ask question.**

Comment: I guess it's more because of "***overly broad** ... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jonathan Lewis covers this in his book Oracle Core (pp.222-225).  I'm not going to recapitulate everything, you should buy the book ([find it here](http://www.apress.com/9781430239543)).  The important thing is that he not only explains what happens, he shows us how we can see what's happening (by using SQL trace).

Basically, each sequence is just a row in the core table `seq$`.  The first call to `nextval` issues an update to that sequence's entry.  This increments the sequence's highwater mark to starting value + cache value. The database tracks the current value (starting value + number of calls to `nextval`) in the SGA; when that number reaches highwater mark the database updates `seq$` again.

The important thing to note is that all this managed in the SGA and not the individual session.  The only thing the individual session tracks is the result of the most recent call to `nextval` so it can satisfy subsequent calls to `currval`.