# order attribute in oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have table with below table structure

```
ACC_ID      ACC_TIMESTAMP
3369376    01-DEC-16 07.21.10
3369379    01-DEC-16 07.25.06
3369371    01-DEC-16 07.30.29
3377485    11-DEC-16 07.47.20
```

Sequence details:

```
CREATED         15-APR-14 09.38.45
LAST_DDL_TIME   15-APR-14 09.38.45
SEQUENCE_OWNER  ACC
SEQUENCE_NAME   ACC_SEQ
MIN_VALUE           1
MAX_VALUE           999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT_BY    1
CYCLE_FLAG          N
ORDER_FLAG          N
CACHE_SIZE          20
LAST_NUMBER         87884
```

If I sort the table in ACC_TIMESTAMP order I see a lesser primary key value 3369371 inserted at 01-DEC-16 07.30.29. How would it be possible when the higher value 3369376 was already inserted at 01-DEC-16 07.21.10? My code expects the increase ordered primary key that should correspond to time-stamp.

I am thinking that setting ORDER_FLAG to Y will follow the order based on timestamp (first come basis). Please help.

Output should be:

```
ACC_ID      ACC_TIMESTAMP
3369376    01-DEC-16 07.21.10
3369379    01-DEC-16 07.25.06
3369381    01-DEC-16 07.30.29 // something higher value like this, but overall sort on both timestamp and PK value.
3377485    11-DEC-16 07.47.20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CREATE-SEQUENCE.htm#SQLRF01314):

> **ORDER**
>
> Specify ORDER to guarantee that sequence numbers are generated in
>   order of request. This clause is useful if you are using the sequence
>   numbers as timestamps. Guaranteeing order is usually not important for
>   sequences used to generate primary keys.

Comment: This should only make a difference in RAC environments

Answer (score 1):

Sequences are managed in the SGA. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383394/146325), but basically the database increments the sequence in request order.

Unless you're on RAC. By default RAC nodes each maintain their own cache of sequence values so numbers run in blocks, and numbers from different nodes are interleaved.

But if you're not on RAC? Perhaps there's some place in the application code where ID and TIMESTAMP aren't grabbed in the same statement. Or someplace where the TIMESTAMP is updated. Without knowing how your ID and TIMESTAMP columns are populated it's pretty hard to be explain.

Also, your posted sequence  details say this ...

```
LAST_NUMBER 87884
```

... but your posted ACC_ID are two orders of magnitude larger.  So perhaps the ACC_ID is actually generated by some other mechanism?

> "My code expects the increase ordered primary key that should correspond to time-stamp."

That's an unwise policy. Unless you can guarantee that both columns are populated in the same statement and *are never tampered with* you should choose one to provide the creation order. Since sequences mainly provide a guaranteed source of unique identifiers probably you should rely on the timestamp.

But if it really matters to you and you're on RAC then by all means use the ORDER clause to guarantee request order:

```
alter sequence ACC_SEQ order;
```

Comment: Thank you APC, I am on RAC and understood that I need to alter the sequence to include order clause.

Comment: I suppose there's no reason why you should have included that crucial piece of information.